# Sphere vs Rotation Box Custom Collision Problem (C#, Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

I'm not really like to post questions about problems without doing the research, but I'm close to give up, so I thought I give it a shot and ask you about my problem.

I want to create a custom collision detection in Unity ( So please don't advice "use rigidbody and\or colliders" because I don't want to use them by purpose).
The main idea: I want to detect Basic Sphere and Basic Box collision. I already find AABB vs Sphere theme with the following solution:

```
bool intersect(sphere, box) {

var x = Math.max(box.minX, Math.min(sphere.x, box.maxX));
var y = Math.max(box.minY, Math.min(sphere.y, box.maxY));
var z = Math.max(box.minZ, Math.min(sphere.z, box.maxZ));

var distance = Math.sqrt((x - sphere.x) * (x - sphere.x) + 
                         (y - sphere.y) * (y - sphere.y) + 
                         (z - sphere.z) * (z - sphere.z));

return distance < sphere.radius;
}
```

And this code does the job, the box bounding and the sphere center point with radius works fine, I can detect the Sphere collision on Box.

The problem is, I want to Rotating the Cube in Runtime, so that will screw up everything, the bounding will split away and the collision will gone (or collide on random places). I've read about some comments where they said, bounding not works with rotation, but I'm not sure what else can I use to solve this problem.

Can you help me with this topic please? I'll take every advice I can get (except Colliders & Rigidbodies of course).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Downvoting my question not really helps guys.... -.-

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the [separating axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem). Essentially, for a polyhedron, you use the normal of each face to create an axis. Project the two shapes you are comparing onto each axis and look for an intersection. If there is no intersection along any of the axes, there is no intersection of shapes. For a sphere, you will just need to project onto the polyhedron's axes. There is a great 2D intro to this from [metanet](https://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html).

Edit: hey, check it out-- [a Unity implementation](https://github.com/irixapps/Unity-Separating-Axis-SAT).

Answer (score 0):

A good method to find if an AABB (axis aligned bounding box) and sphere are intersecting is to find the closest point on the box to the sphere's center and determine if that point is within the sphere's radius. If so, then they are intersecting, if not then not.

I believe you can do the same thing with this more complicated scenario. You can represent a rotated AABB with a geometrical shape called a parallelepiped. You would then find the closest point on the parallelepiped to the center of the sphere and again check if that point exists within the sphere's radius. If so, then they intersect. If not, then not.

The difficult part is finding the closest point on the parallelepiped. You can represent a parallelepiped in code with 4 3d vectors: center, extentRight, extentUp, and extentForward. This is similar to how you can represent an AABB with a 3d vector for center along with 3 floats: extentRight, extentUp, and extentForward. The difference is that for the parallelepiped those 3 extents are not 1 dimensional scalars, but are full vectors.

When finding the closest point on an AABB surface to a given point, you are basically taking that given point and clamping it to the AABB's volume. You would, for example, call Math.Clamp(point.x, AABB.Min.x, AABB.Max.x) and so on for Y and Z.
The resulting X,Y,Z would be the closest point on the AABB surface to the given point.

To do this for a parallelepiped you need to solve the "linear combination" (math keyword) of extentRight(ER), extentUp(EU), and extentForward(EF) to get the given point. In other words, what scalars do you have to multiply ER, EU, and EF by to get to the given point? When you find those scalars you need to clamp them between 0 and 1 and then multiply them again by ER, EU, and EF respectively to get that closest point on the surface of the parallelepiped. Be sure to offset the given point by the Parallelepiped's min position so that the whole calculation is done in its local space.

I didn't want to spend any extra time learning how to solve for a linear combination (it seems it involves things like using an "augmented matrix" and "gaussian elimination") otherwise I'd include that here too. This should get you or anyone else reading this off to the right track hopefully.

Edit:
Actually I think its a lot simpler and you don't need a parallelepiped. If you have access to the rotation (Vector3 or Quaternion) that rotated the cube you could get the inverse of that and use that inverse rotation to orbit the sphere around the cube so that the new scenario is just the normal axis aligned cube and the orbited sphere. Then you can do a normal AABB - sphere collision detection.